# Insert variables into MySQL database

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I try to post values from Android application into a remote MySQL database.
Database table looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIZUO.png).

```
           try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Connection conn = null;
                try {
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://myhost:3306/mydb",
                            "root", "root");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Connected to Database");
                Statement stmt1 = null;
                try {
                    stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ResultSet rs1=null;
                PreparedStatement sql = null;
                try {
                    sql = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `mytable`(studentid,classid,startsig,start,end,endsig) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //set values before sending
                try {
                sql.setString(1, studentid);
                sql.setString(2, classid);
                sql.setString(3, startsig);
                sql.setString(4, start);
                sql.setString(5, end);
                sql.setString(5, endsig);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("sql:"+sql);
                try {
                    stmt1.executeUpdate(String.valueOf(sql));
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I have got error message below for this code:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Error message says, that no suitable driver was found for this operation.

Comment: where is that running? What is your classpath? What is in it? Is there a servlet container involved? What version of jdbc?

Comment: Which version of JDBC should I use?

Comment: Not much of an answer or details of your environment. Good luck :p

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in you build file.

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.5'
}
```

Comment: It was not worked and I found that this method is obsolete, so I implemented another solution.

Answer (score -1):

You must put the mysql-connector.jar in your application classpath!  The application didnt found the class because its not there.

You can download it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

**Edit 1**

Try something like this to add it in your Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.+'
 }
```

Comment: Could you please explain, how can I add this dependency with use of Gradle?

Comment: @appkovacs, See if my edit 1 fits for you. Besosdes that,  could post your gradle build file here?

Comment: I got error message: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.